# Can we update solr index and schema's within multiplecore without restarting solr?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a situation where I need to update/add a new schema for a solr index.
In the worst case I also have to update/add new index to the running solr.
Can I do that without restarting the solr?
Can adding a new core to the multicore space will be possible without needing to restart the solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this with the Solr Core Administration.

> Since Solr1.3, SolrCore can optionally be managed at runtime. Additionally, Solr allows multiple SolrCore instances to run within a single web-app. The cores can be dynamically managed via the CoreAdminHandler.

For all of the details, please reference the [CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) section of Solr Wiki.

Comment: Thank you @Paige, The CoreAdmin section of solr wiki says that the new core can be created using preexisting instanceDir/schema.xml. However in my case I need to create new schema without using preexisting instanceDir/schema.xml, so will that be possible.

Comment: When they state pre-existing, they mean that the files must exist on the disk on the server prior to executing the CREATE command. I just tried copying an existing core folder to a new folder name and used the CREATE command to set it up as a new core and it worked successfully. I was running on Solr v3.2.

Comment: ok @Paige I got it that should work fine. Thank you once again.